# Reference Model fields in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Model:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
  q1 = "What is your favourite colour?"
  a1 = models.CharField()
```

I'd like to use a ModelForm and override the labels something like this:

```
class QuestionnaireForm(forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionnaireForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['a1'].label = q1

  class Meta:
    model = Questionnaire
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out while writing it, so here's the answer for posterity:

```
self.fields['a1'].label = self.Meta.model.q1
```

etc...